# Time Series list as dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I have `c1` is a list which contains 8 time series data frames, each data frame has different number of columns it varies from 372 to 432. Now i need to use many functions of an R package named `hyfo` and I need to use this function

```
> df <- list2Dataframe(novo)
```

but it returns me

> ```
> Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE,
> check.names = TRUE,  :    arguments imply differing number of rows:
> 432, 408, 360, 372
> ```

And in the example data `testdl` of the package there are different number of rows of each dataframe and it doesn't return any error using the `list2Dataframe` function and many others that I need.

Help me please,

Kevin

Edit: Variable novo is the result of:
 As you can see is a list of 5 dataframes, with two columns each, a date and an observation.

```
> novo <- extractPeriod(c2, commonPeriod = TRUE )

> dput(novo)
list(structure(list(FECHA = structure(c(3652, 3683, 3712, 3743, 
3773, 3804, 3834, 3865, 3896, 3926, 3957, 3987, 4018, 4049, 4077, 
4108, 4138, 4169, 4199, 4230, 4261, 4291, 4322, 4352, 4383, 4414, 
4442, 4473, 4503, 4534, 4564, 4595, 4626, 4656, 4687, 4717, 4748, 
4779, 4807, 4838, 4868, 4899, 4929, 4960, 4991, 5021, 5052, 5082, 
5113, 5144, 5173, 5204, 5234, 5265, 5295, 5326, 5357, 5387, 5418, 
5448, 5479, 5510, 5538, 5569, 5599, 5630, 5660, 5691, 5722, 5752, 
5783, 5813, 5844, 5875, 5903, 5934, 5964, 5995, 6025, 6056, 6087, 
6117, 6148, 6178, 6209, 6240, 6268, 6299, 6329, 6360, 6390, 6421, 
6452, 6482, 6513, 6543, 6574, 6605, 6634, 6665, 6695, 6726, 6756, 
6787, 6818, 6848, 6879, 6909, 6940, 6971, 6999, 7030, 7060, 7091, 
7121, 7152, 7183, 7213, 7244, 7274, 7305, 7336, 7364, 7395, 7425, 
7456, 7486, 7517, 7548, 7578, 7609, 7639, 7670, 7701, 7729, 7760, 
7790, 7821, 7851, 7882, 7913, 7943, 7974, 8004, 8035, 8066, 8095, 
8126, 8156, 8187, 8217, 8248, 8279, 8309, 8340, 8370, 8401, 8432, 
8460, 8491, 8521, 8552, 8582, 8613, 8644, 8674, 8705, 8735, 8766, 
8797, 8825, 8856, 8886, 8917, 8947, 8978, 9009, 9039, 9070, 9100, 
9131, 9162, 9190, 9221, 9251, 9282, 9312, 9343, 9374, 9404, 9435, 
9465, 9496, 9527, 9556, 9587, 9617, 9648, 9678, 9709, 9740, 9770, 
9801, 9831, 9862, 9893, 9921, 9952, 9982, 10013, 10043, 10074, 
10105, 10135, 10166, 10196, 10227, 10258, 10286, 10317, 10347, 
10378, 10408, 10439, 10470, 10500, 10531, 10561, 10592, 10623, 
10651, 10682, 10712, 10743, 10773, 10804, 10835, 10865, 10896, 
10926, 10957, 10988, 11017, 11048, 11078, 11109, 11139, 11170, 
11201, 11231, 11262, 11292, 11323, 11354, 11382, 11413, 11443, 
11474, 11504, 11535, 11566, 11596, 11627, 11657, 11688, 11719, 
11747, 11778, 11808, 11839, 11869, 11900, 11931, 11961, 11992, 
12022, 12053, 12084, 12112, 12143, 12173, 12204, 12234, 12265, 
12296, 12326, 12357, 12387, 12418, 12449, 12478, 12509, 12539, 
12570, 12600, 12631, 12662, 12692, 12723, 12753, 12784, 12815, 
12843, 12874, 12904, 12935, 12965, 12996, 13027, 13057, 13088, 
13118, 13149, 13180, 13208, 13239, 13269, 13300, 13330, 13361, 
13392, 13422, 13453, 13483, 13514, 13545, 13573, 13604, 13634, 
13665, 13695, 13726, 13757, 13787, 13818, 13848, 13879, 13910, 
13939, 13970, 14000, 14031, 14061, 14092, 14123, 14153, 14184, 
14214, 14245, 14276, 14304, 14335, 14365, 14396, 14426, 14457, 
14488, 14518, 14549, 14579, 14610, 14641, 14669, 14700, 14730, 
14761, 14791, 14822, 14853, 14883, 14914, 14944, 14975, 15006, 
15034, 15065, 15095, 15126, 15156, 15187, 15218, 15248, 15279, 
15309, 15340, 15371, 15400, 15431, 15461, 15492, 15522, 15553, 
15584, 15614, 15645, 15675, 15706, 15737, 15765, 15796, 15826, 
15857, 15887, 15918, 15949, 15979, 16010, 16040, 16071, 16102, 
16130, 16161, 16191, 16222, 16252, 16283, 16314, 16344, 16375, 
16405, 16436, 16467, 16495, 16526, 16556, 16587, 16617, 16648, 
16679, 16709, 16740, 16770), class = "Date"), El.Corazón..21201070.I = c(43, 
105, 38, 66, 119, 57, 30, 61, 111, 66.6, 59.9, 61.7, 9.6, 143.5, 
73.2, 153.4, 139.7, 96.6, 27.7, 71.2, 22.1, 197.9, 30.8, 30.7, 
53.2, 126.2, 121.1, 107.2, 128.1, NA, 35.3, 4.4, 61.7, 104.5, 
101.3, 92.7, 27.7, 50.5, 56.3, 228.4, 66.5, 22.7, 25.4, 28.4, 
45.2, 124.4, 15.2, 78.1, 85.6, 7.8, 21.5, 78.7, 134.6, 75.2, 
48.8, 97.4, 80, 35.6, 86.8, 32.2, 32.2, 63.4, 33.4, 50.1, 66.1, 
24.7, 32.3, 83.2, 129.1, 176, 178.1, 18.2, 33.4, 82, 37.8, 91.9, 
22.7, 28.6, 4.7, 33.6, 60, 238.3, 171.1, 19.6, 21.8, 11.3, 51.4, 
78.4, 80.9, 9.3, 67.6, 24.1, 62.8, 99, 140.8, NA, 32.7, 54.9, 
135.7, 73.2, 84.1, 19.7, 75.6, 109.7, NA, 10.5, 87.3, 56.7, 23.4, 
6.8, 141.3, 10, 43.5, 37.9, 41.1, 65.4, 9.9, 37.5, 22.3, 20.1, 
18.1, 120.8, 22.9, 68.8, 14.2, 23.8, 30.9, 38.9, 27.1, 85, 20.9, 
137.4, 39.3, 123.9, 137, NA, NA, 22, 59.7, 14.2, 35.5, 17, 89.2, 
53.3, 7.1, 32, NA, 68.5, 46.6, 33.5, 52.6, 49.5, 19.6, 26.4, 
53.3, 23.1, 16.7, 71.2, 79.3, 36.3, 74.5, 18.5, 30.4, 23.8, 72.1, 
23.5, 79.3, 21.2, 40.6, 49.6, 35.5, 68.1, 88, 41.4, 39.9, 31.7, 
29.3, 110.5, 96, 32.7, 6.4, 86.9, 182.5, 85.4, 139.3, 118.4, 
94.2, 123.1, 35.8, 69.4, 66.8, 64.5, 110.3, 74.7, 155.4, 102.5, 
152.9, 103.2, 61.2, 61.7, 24.5, 142.2, 90.7, 65, 91.6, 19, 109, 
92, 61.5, 78.5, 29.5, 6.4, 28.4, 67.8, 70.2, 5.6, 18.7, 37.2, 
57.2, 86.9, 112.5, 51.1, 59.3, 46.1, 62.9, 121.4, 84.2, 41.9, 
64.3, 149.7, 79.4, 131.3, 75.6, 98.6, 19, 87.8, 114.8, 86.4, 
176.4, 95.7, 62.2, 114.5, 55.1, 55.7, 43.4, 34.1, 47.3, 47.6, 
107.7, 114.3, 66.3, 48.2, 42.2, 34.1, 73, 24, 101.9, 38.5, 25.4, 
24.8, 71.5, 81.4, 96.1, 119.7, 13.1, 31.1, 123.2, 161.8, 88.1, 
63.6, 12.8, 7.9, 34.1, 73.6, 64, 28.7, 4.2, 63.8, 84.2, 93.6, 
37.5, 63.2, 30.4, 66.8, 56.7, 146.6, 152.3, 87.5, 71.8, 75.9, 
176.9, 126.1, 115.6, 32.2, 75.7, 13.7, 98.8, 126.4, 137, 41.7, 
113.1, 57.8, 2.4, 67, 157.9, 26.6, 18.8, 59.5, 61.8, 157, 95.8, 
15.6, 38, 36.7, 198.4, 190, 139.7, 119.1, 31.4, 24.8, 28.6, 116.3, 
125.5, 36.5, 21.7, 6, 82.6, 80, 78.5, 97.7, 25.2, 108.2, 28.3, 
159.7, 137.8, 110.1, 77.8, 56.4, 135.5, 123.9, NA, NA, NA, 89.8, 
55.7, 157.2, 189.6, 68.1, 43, 62.3, 133.3, 90.9, 75.6, 60.9, 
25.6, 28.1, 26.4, 99, 137, 5.4, 9.6, 30.2, 26.1, 154.7, 192.3, 
92.5, 171.5, 73.6, 97.7, 91.1, 204.4, 119.1, 30.3, 67.8, 151.9, 
200.9, 162.8, 116.6, 44.5, 69.2, 34.6, 230.1, 187.2, 80.4, 109.9, 
57.7, 101.6, 98.7, 70.7, 32.4, 56.2, 24.3, 37.8, 91.3, 68.7, 
35.9, 66.9, 113.1, 153.4, 97, 121.2, 41.3, 14.8, 90.1, 16.8, 
87.2, 141.4, 117, 92.4, 67.2, 101.6, 59.8, 92.3, 52.4, 56.4, 
28.3, 28.6, 148.1, 106.8, 50.6, 21.6, 43.6, 103.9, 101.6, 15.3, 
62.5, 33.2, 36.3, 35.1, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("FECHA", "El.Corazón..21201070.I"
), row.names = c(NA, 432L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(
    FECHA = structure(c(3652, 3683, 3712, 3743, 3773, 3804, 3834, 
    3865, 3896, 3926, 3957, 3987, 4018, 4049, 4077, 4108, 4138, 
    4169, 4199, 4230, 4261, 4291, 4322, 4352, 4383, 4414, 4442, 
    4473, 4503, 4534, 4564, 4595, 4626, 4656, 4687, 4717, 4748, 
    4779, 4807, 4838, 4868, 4899, 4929, 4960, 4991, 5021, 5052, 
    5082, 5113, 5144, 5173, 5204, 5234, 5265, 5295, 5326, 5357, 
    5387, 5418, 5448, 5479, 5510, 5538, 5569, 5599, 5630, 5660, 
    5691, 5722, 5752, 5783, 5813, 5844, 5875, 5903, 5934, 5964, 
    5995, 6025, 6056, 6087, 6117, 6148, 6178, 6209, 6240, 6268, 
    6299, 6329, 6360, 6390, 6421, 6452, 6482, 6513, 6543, 6574, 
    6605, 6634, 6665, 6695, 6726, 6756, 6787, 6818, 6848, 6879, 
    6909, 7670, 7701, 7729, 7760, 7790, 7821, 7851, 7882, 7913, 
    7943, 7974, 8004, 8035, 8066, 8095, 8126, 8156, 8187, 8217, 
    8248, 8279, 8309, 8340, 8370, 8401, 8432, 8460, 8491, 8521, 
    8552, 8582, 8613, 8644, 8674, 8705, 8735, 8766, 8797, 8825, 
    8856, 8886, 8917, 8947, 8978, 9009, 9039, 9070, 9100, 9131, 
    9162, 9190, 9221, 9251, 9282, 9312, 9343, 9374, 9404, 9435, 
    9465, 9496, 9527, 9556, 9587, 9617, 9648, 9678, 9709, 9740, 
    9770, 9801, 9831, 9862, 9893, 9921, 9952, 9982, 10013, 10043, 
    10074, 10105, 10135, 10166, 10196, 10227, 10258, 10286, 10317, 
    10347, 10378, 10408, 10439, 10470, 10500, 10531, 10561, 10592, 
    10623, 10651, 10682, 10712, 10743, 10773, 10804, 10835, 10865, 
    10896, 10926, 10957, 10988, 11017, 11048, 11078, 11109, 11139, 
    11170, 11201, 11231, 11262, 11292, 11323, 11354, 11382, 11413, 
    11443, 11474, 11504, 11535, 11566, 11596, 11627, 11657, 11688, 
    11719, 11747, 11778, 11808, 11839, 11869, 11900, 11931, 11961, 
    11992, 12022, 12053, 12084, 12112, 12143, 12173, 12204, 12234, 
    12265, 12296, 12326, 12357, 12387, 12418, 12449, 12478, 12509, 
    12539, 12570, 12600, 12631, 12662, 12692, 12723, 12753, 12784, 
    12815, 12843, 12874, 12904, 12935, 12965, 12996, 13027, 13057, 
    13088, 13118, 13149, 13180, 13208, 13239, 13269, 13300, 13330, 
    13361, 13392, 13422, 13453, 13483, 13514, 13545, 13573, 13604, 
    13634, 13665, 13695, 13726, 13757, 13787, 13818, 13848, 13879, 
    13910, 13939, 13970, 14000, 14031, 14061, 14092, 14123, 14153, 
    14184, 14214, 14245, 14276, 14304, 14335, 14365, 14396, 14426, 
    14457, 14488, 14518, 14549, 14579, 14610, 14641, 14669, 14700, 
    14730, 14761, 14791, 14822, 14853, 14883, 14914, 14944, 14975, 
    15006, 15034, 15065, 15095, 15126, 15156, 15187, 15218, 15248, 
    15279, 15309, 15340, 15371, 15400, 15431, 15461, 15492, 15522, 
    15553, 15584, 15614, 15645, 15675, 15706, 15737, 15765, 15796, 
    15826, 15857, 15887, 15918, 15949, 15979, 16010, 16040, 16071, 
    16102, 16130, 16161, 16191, 16222, 16252, 16283, 16314, 16344, 
    16375, 16405, 16436, 16467, 16495, 16526, 16556, 16587, 16617, 
    16648, 16679, 16709, 16740, 16770), class = "Date"), La.Primavera..2120557.C = c(13.1, 
    41, 10.9, 52.7, 58.4, 68.9, 19.3, 51.1, 79.3, 109.9, 61.2, 
    21.7, 24.2, 17.4, 43, 147.9, 210.9, 66.6, 33.6, 45.6, 23.6, 
    187.6, 44.4, 49, 23, 88.4, 100.7, 167.9, 110.4, 47.8, 29.5, 
    18.4, 82, 97.2, 58.7, 31.1, 23, 32.9, 65.8, 212.1, 74.6, 
    46.8, 48.8, 28.2, 23.7, 73.2, 37.2, 74.4, 70.9, 51.4, 29.8, 
    95.6, 68.8, 84.2, 37, 81.2, 122.3, 71.6, 127.3, 30.1, 2.8, 
    16.1, 35.3, 43.1, 107.6, 24.3, 58.4, 89.2, 100.2, 106.9, 
    88, 15.7, 43.7, 58.6, 23.8, 121.3, 119.4, 77.9, 29.3, 38.5, 
    62.1, 192.4, 159.1, 41.5, 64.1, 36.6, 23.2, 44.4, 150, 23.6, 
    73.7, 24.1, 72, 143.5, 49.9, 16.3, 24, 31.1, 9.2, 56.8, 108, 
    99.1, 68.6, 65, 100, 138.7, 123.7, 54.2, 15.4, 27.2, 168.9, 
    174.8, 85.9, 25.5, 60.7, 42.3, 61.8, 44.3, 96.4, 38, 12.2, 
    43, 10.6, 29.7, 33.3, 31, 58.9, 36.4, 57.4, 37.8, 99.5, 58.9, 
    41.8, 47.8, 122.5, 75.5, 97.7, 46.8, 50.8, 17.8, 85.3, 35.4, 
    158.9, 40.5, 37.2, 60.5, 93.4, 109.9, 96.1, 49.2, 49.8, 52.8, 
    47.1, 103.5, 141.1, 8, 3.8, 41.8, 115.9, 77.7, 103.9, 78.1, 
    98.7, 118.3, 60.3, 72, 36.2, 97.3, 33.2, 64.4, 126.6, 47.4, 
    79.9, 67.2, 87.8, 36, 73, 93.2, 52.2, 36.2, 34, 9.8, 73, 
    83.5, 53, 71.6, 28, 18.1, 46.7, 63.5, 48.8, 1.2, 25.3, 47, 
    39.5, 101.2, 115.3, 36.2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 79.6, 70.1, 
    70, 70.9, 51.6, 79.1, 34.7, 115.5, 100.2, 184, 84.8, 50, 
    27.8, 89.2, 85.9, 72.9, 43.8, 43.5, 50.2, 34.8, 120.1, 99.3, 
    35, 25.4, 42.3, 16.4, 95.6, 11, 105.7, 39.1, 35, 23.7, 76.1, 
    38.3, 36.7, 129.3, 27.2, 9.1, 96.3, 173.3, 65.3, 51.9, 17.4, 
    19, 40.6, 37, 36.3, 62.9, NA, 18, 54.7, 126, 32.6, NA, 35.1, 
    26.3, 58.7, 145.6, 65.5, 43.9, 23.4, 33.7, 76.1, 121.6, 102.1, 
    39.6, 50.3, 19, 74, 111.3, 77.3, 20.2, 30.8, 39.5, 9.2, 98.6, 
    144.3, 52, 22.8, 71.5, 125.9, 148.5, 35.7, NA, 180.6, 102, 
    199.6, 283.9, 330.1, 82.3, NA, NA, 35.9, 121.5, 51.8, 36.3, 
    8.9, 13, 80.3, 127.5, 56.6, 79.8, 35.1, 71.7, 50.7, 195.2, 
    60.5, 117.1, 52.1, 58.5, 71.2, 96.3, 108.3, 82.8, 90.3, 88.5, 
    112.9, 109.1, 118.6, 24.4, 35.6, 61.1, 127.9, 67, 29.4, 99.2, 
    21.2, 10.1, 13.2, 81.2, 104.7, 9.6, 8.4, 10.5, 4.1, 100.9, 
    60, 119.8, 201.9, 76.8, 48.7, 14.3, 163.5, 86.8, 32, 42, 
    135.9, 222.1, 163.6, 64, 104.3, 39.6, 88.1, 176.1, 240.3, 
    60, 41.3, 25.5, 116.7, 221.6, 62.6, 31.8, 50.5, 46.1, 32.3, 
    88.4, 30.6, 16.6, 22, 62.5, 86.7, 119.5, 116.5, 33.6, 32.3, 
    76.1, 45.5, 72.8, 74.7, 82.4, 62.1, 97.1, 51.2, 55.5, 41.6, 
    65.1, 40.7, 30.2, 29, 294.2, 88.7, 43.9, 47.2, 34.1, 47.6, 
    100.4, 25.3, 50.6, 42.2, 37.3, 17.2, 19.6, 0.5, NA)), .Names = c("FECHA", 
"La.Primavera..2120557.C"), row.names = c(NA, 408L), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(FECHA = structure(c(3652, 3683, 3712, 3743, 
    3773, 3804, 3834, 3865, 3896, 3926, 3957, 3987, 4018, 4049, 
    4077, 4108, 4138, 4169, 4199, 4230, 4261, 4291, 4322, 4352, 
    4383, 4414, 4442, 4473, 4503, 4534, 4564, 4595, 4626, 4656, 
    4687, 4717, 6209, 6240, 6268, 6299, 6329, 6360, 6390, 6421, 
    6452, 6482, 6513, 6543, 6574, 6605, 6634, 6665, 6695, 6726, 
    6756, 6787, 6818, 6848, 6879, 6909, 7670, 7701, 7729, 7760, 
    7790, 7821, 7851, 7882, 7913, 7943, 7974, 8004, 8035, 8066, 
    8095, 8126, 8156, 8187, 8217, 8248, 8279, 8309, 8340, 8370, 
    8401, 8432, 8460, 8491, 8521, 8552, 8582, 8613, 8644, 8674, 
    8705, 8735, 8766, 8797, 8825, 8856, 8886, 8917, 8947, 8978, 
    9009, 9039, 9070, 9100, 9131, 9162, 9190, 9221, 9251, 9282, 
    9312, 9343, 9374, 9404, 9435, 9465, 9496, 9527, 9556, 9587, 
    9617, 9648, 9678, 9709, 9740, 9770, 9801, 9831, 9862, 9893, 
    9921, 9952, 9982, 10013, 10043, 10074, 10105, 10135, 10166, 
    10196, 10227, 10258, 10286, 10317, 10347, 10378, 10408, 10439, 
    10470, 10500, 10531, 10561, 10592, 10623, 10651, 10682, 10712, 
    10743, 10773, 10804, 10835, 10865, 10896, 10926, 10957, 10988, 
    11017, 11048, 11078, 11109, 11139, 11170, 11201, 11231, 11262, 
    11292, 11323, 11354, 11382, 11413, 11443, 11474, 11504, 11535, 
    11566, 11596, 11627, 11657, 11688, 11719, 11747, 11778, 11808, 
    11839, 11869, 11900, 11931, 11961, 11992, 12022, 12053, 12084, 
    12112, 12143, 12173, 12204, 12234, 12265, 12296, 12326, 12357, 
    12387, 12418, 12449, 12478, 12509, 12539, 12570, 12600, 12631, 
    12662, 12692, 12723, 12753, 12784, 12815, 12843, 12874, 12904, 
    12935, 12965, 12996, 13027, 13057, 13088, 13118, 13149, 13180, 
    13208, 13239, 13269, 13300, 13330, 13361, 13392, 13422, 13453, 
    13483, 13514, 13545, 13573, 13604, 13634, 13665, 13695, 13726, 
    13757, 13787, 13818, 13848, 13879, 13910, 13939, 13970, 14000, 
    14031, 14061, 14092, 14123, 14153, 14184, 14214, 14245, 14276, 
    14304, 14335, 14365, 14396, 14426, 14457, 14488, 14518, 14549, 
    14579, 14610, 14641, 14669, 14700, 14730, 14761, 14791, 14822, 
    14853, 14883, 14914, 14944, 14975, 15006, 15034, 15065, 15095, 
    15126, 15156, 15187, 15218, 15248, 15279, 15309, 15340, 15371, 
    15400, 15431, 15461, 15492, 15522, 15553, 15584, 15614, 15645, 
    15675, 15706, 15737, 15765, 15796, 15826, 15857, 15887, 15918, 
    15949, 15979, 16010, 16040, 16071, 16102, 16130, 16161, 16191, 
    16222, 16252, 16283, 16314, 16344, 16375, 16405, 16436, 16467, 
    16495, 16526, 16556, 16587, 16617, 16648, 16679, 16709, 16740, 
    16770), class = "Date"), La.Unión..2120055.C = c(43.5, 92, 
    34, 78, 102.5, 88.5, 34, 51.5, 29, 38, 11, 11, NA, 9, 27, 
    93, 171, 86, 18, 62, 45.5, 175, 71.5, 42, 33, 162, 89, 144, 
    155, 60, 32.5, 13, 72.6, 89, 99.4, 53.8, 36, 79, 28, 65, 
    156, 15, 88, 15, 100, 163, 97, NA, 12.8, 50.2, 26.2, 122.7, 
    14.4, 74.5, 74.6, 63.4, 62.3, 110.2, 97.1, 100.1, 80.5, 42, 
    218, 94, 180, 32.5, 34.5, 38.5, 76, 42.5, 106.5, 75.5, 5.5, 
    59.5, 29.5, 35, 49, 35, 71, 21, 56, 41, 123, 61, 68.9, 82.5, 
    169.5, 183, 145, 33.5, 60, 13.5, 104, 69.5, 209.5, 116.5, 
    39, 73, 35, 122.5, 74.5, 106, 46.5, 61, 45.5, 103, 93, 10, 
    NA, 41, 109.5, 180.5, 179.5, 74, 91.5, 124, 27, 113, 32, 
    94.5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 34.5, 68.5, 45, 51, 135, 12.5, 
    107, 77.5, 36.5, 108, 72.5, 60.5, 72, 18.5, 21, 56.5, 62.8, 
    82, NA, 27, 44, 31, 113.8, 116, 57.4, 48, 68.1, 67.1, 154.5, 
    109.5, 90.5, 73.5, 154.1, 93.8, 70, 77.5, 131.5, 27.5, 94.7, 
    143.5, 166, 203.5, 96, 35.5, 95.5, 77.5, 48.5, 22.9, 45, 
    46.2, 45.5, 121.5, 92.5, 117, 54, 35.1, 43, 104, 29.5, 153, 
    36.5, 31.5, 16, 110.5, 76.5, 77.5, 148, 16, 5.5, 97, 234, 
    90.5, 58.5, 12.5, 16, 36.5, 138, 37, 74.5, 20.2, 54.5, 85.5, 
    188.5, 71.5, NA, 82, 29, 120, 162, 93, 62, 45, 64, 149, 150, 
    114, 38, 72, 29, 135, 137, 133, 25, NA, 65, 5, 96, 123, 26, 
    16, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 49, 12, 193.5, 216.2, 100.9, 132, 
    33.3, 53, 32.9, 281.1, 67.6, 47.1, 17.4, NA, 61.5, 130.2, 
    61.5, 66.5, 21.3, 120, 41, 220, 140, 168.2, 86, 114, 117.2, 
    134, 207, 110, 121, 117, 104, 159, NA, NA, 51, 68, 156, 102, 
    80, 115, 13, 18, 20, 125, 192, 5, 12, 21, 8, 226, 285, 152, 
    249, 66, 125, 121, 110, 172, 38, 91, 190, 220, 193, 88, 52, 
    70, 95, 368, 271, 137, 94, 14, 127, 194, 93, 42, 84, 54, 
    36, 188, 64, 37, 13, 106, 134, 179, 234, 45, 27, 20.7, 39.5, 
    105, 154, 165, 74.7, 130.7, 105.8, 118.8, 154.9, 73, 63.2, 
    96, 80, 248, 175, 53, 56, 50, 40, 122, 41, 76, 77, 45, 11, 
    24.6, 109, NA)), .Names = c("FECHA", "La.Unión..2120055.C"
    ), row.names = c(NA, 360L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(
        FECHA = structure(c(3652, 3683, 3712, 3743, 3773, 3804, 
        3834, 3865, 3896, 3926, 3957, 3987, 4018, 4049, 4077, 
        4108, 4138, 4169, 4199, 4230, 4261, 4291, 4322, 4352, 
        4383, 4414, 4442, 4473, 4503, 4534, 4564, 4595, 4626, 
        4656, 4687, 4717, 6209, 6240, 6268, 6299, 6329, 6360, 
        6390, 6421, 6452, 6482, 6513, 6543, 6574, 6605, 6634, 
        6665, 6695, 6726, 6756, 6787, 6818, 6848, 6879, 6909, 
        7670, 7701, 7729, 7760, 7790, 7821, 7851, 7882, 7913, 
        7943, 7974, 8004, 8035, 8066, 8095, 8126, 8156, 8187, 
        8217, 8248, 8279, 8309, 8340, 8370, 8401, 8432, 8460, 
        8491, 8521, 8552, 8582, 8613, 8644, 8674, 8705, 8735, 
        8766, 8797, 8825, 8856, 8886, 8917, 8947, 8978, 9009, 
        9039, 9070, 9100, 9131, 9162, 9190, 9221, 9251, 9282, 
        9312, 9343, 9374, 9404, 9435, 9465, 9496, 9527, 9556, 
        9587, 9617, 9648, 9678, 9709, 9740, 9770, 9801, 9831, 
        9862, 9893, 9921, 9952, 9982, 10013, 10043, 10074, 10105, 
        10135, 10166, 10196, 10227, 10258, 10286, 10317, 10347, 
        10378, 10408, 10439, 10470, 10500, 10531, 10561, 10592, 
        10623, 10651, 10682, 10712, 10743, 10773, 10804, 10835, 
        10865, 10896, 10926, 10957, 10988, 11017, 11048, 11078, 
        11109, 11139, 11170, 11201, 11231, 11262, 11292, 11323, 
        11354, 11382, 11413, 11443, 11474, 11504, 11535, 11566, 
        11596, 11627, 11657, 11688, 11719, 11747, 11778, 11808, 
        11839, 11869, 11900, 11931, 11961, 11992, 12022, 12053, 
        12084, 12112, 12143, 12173, 12204, 12234, 12265, 12296, 
        12326, 12357, 12387, 12418, 12449, 12478, 12509, 12539, 
        12570, 12600, 12631, 12662, 12692, 12723, 12753, 12784, 
        12815, 12843, 12874, 12904, 12935, 12965, 12996, 13027, 
        13057, 13088, 13118, 13149, 13180, 13208, 13239, 13269, 
        13300, 13330, 13361, 13392, 13422, 13453, 13483, 13514, 
        13545, 13573, 13604, 13634, 13665, 13695, 13726, 13757, 
        13787, 13818, 13848, 13879, 13910, 13939, 13970, 14000, 
        14031, 14061, 14092, 14123, 14153, 14184, 14214, 14245, 
        14276, 14304, 14335, 14365, 14396, 14426, 14457, 14488, 
        14518, 14549, 14579, 14610, 14641, 14669, 14700, 14730, 
        14761, 14791, 14822, 14853, 14883, 14914, 14944, 14975, 
        15006, 15034, 15065, 15095, 15126, 15156, 15187, 15218, 
        15248, 15279, 15309, 15340, 15371, 15400, 15431, 15461, 
        15492, 15522, 15553, 15584, 15614, 15645, 15675, 15706, 
        15737, 15765, 15796, 15826, 15857, 15887, 15918, 15949, 
        15979, 16010, 16040, 16071, 16102, 16130, 16161, 16191, 
        16222, 16252, 16283, 16314, 16344, 16375, 16405, 16436, 
        16467, 16495, 16526, 16556, 16587, 16617, 16648, 16679, 
        16709, 16740, 16770), class = "Date"), Tesoro = c(NA, 
        58.5, 49.5, 5, 72, 73, 92.5, NA, 51.5, 50, 142.5, 50, 
        NA, 7, 21, 61.5, 178.5, 107, 53, 48, 65, 48, 82, 88.5, 
        NA, 36, 113, 99, 90.5, 95, 61.5, 31.5, 10, 37.5, 39, 
        76, NA, 97, 64, 78, 102, 114, 43, 163, 65, 110, 105, 
        65, NA, 8, 45, 30, 56.5, 37, 110, 74, 81, 113, 106, 94, 
        NA, 15, 52, 70, 80, 125, 80, 30, 69, 50, 90, 37.5, NA, 
        5, 6, 5.8, 31.6, 22, 19.6, 45.3, 59.2, 140.7, 82.7, 160.1, 
        NA, 25.3, 49.2, 84.4, 75.3, 96.2, 38, 33.1, 21.5, 59.1, 
        25.6, 112.2, NA, 24.5, 35.6, 54, 91.5, 75.3, 38, 130.1, 
        85, 78, 181, 185, NA, 38, 29.5, 86.8, 77, 178.8, 186, 
        111, 180, 101, 52, 87, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 224, 259, 
        186, 210, 266.5, 167, NA, 164, 271, 116, 256, 62.5, 70.3, 
        56.6, 78.9, NA, 73, 175.5, NA, 16, 79, 67, 92, 203.5, 
        118.5, 156.1, 130.6, 292.5, 169, 170.2, NA, 173.5, 420.5, 
        345.3, 221, 190, 247, 218.6, 208, 171.5, 159.6, 51, NA, 
        38.1, 24, 36.4, 49.5, 51, 82.7, 95, 108, 250.3, 100.2, 
        54.3, NA, 12.1, 3.2, 75.5, 9, 119.3, 43, 55.8, 113.4, 
        116.5, 57.1, 73.4, NA, 9, 18, 116.5, 179.6, 91.3, 112.5, 
        36.3, 55, 80.4, 122.1, 117.3, NA, NA, 58.6, 97.6, 158.6, 
        24.5, NA, NA, 86, 55.6, 294.4, 192.9, NA, 31, 59.5, 91.7, 
        290.3, 194.7, 111.5, 64.3, 21.2, 115.7, 242.1, 200, NA, 
        32, 71, 246, 86, 198.5, 9.5, 12.5, 6, 165.8, 162, 109, 
        NA, NA, NA, 282, 209.7, 173.1, 73, 28.5, 30, 55.3, 169.5, 
        92.6, NA, 32, NA, 48.1, 92.6, 36.8, 86.3, 30.1, 74.1, 
        13, 201.9, 91.9, NA, 41.2, 23.5, 35.4, 123.6, 138, 51.8, 
        66.9, 80.9, 44.1, 144.1, 173.3, NA, 22.1, 58.2, 85.5, 
        64.4, 49.1, 56.1, 28.7, 36.9, 14.6, 96.4, 84.3, NA, 11.7, 
        30.5, 3.6, 75.6, 108.8, 84.2, 158.7, 25, 69.8, 59.8, 
        177.6, NA, 21.4, 23.5, 97.6, 114.4, 150, 41.3, 37.2, 
        24, 54.1, 221.9, 171, NA, 43.1, 38.6, 159.9, 99, 74.9, 
        25.6, 48.4, 60.1, 9.3, 88.6, 65.2, NA, 26.1, 43.2, 74.6, 
        83.7, 114.2, 25.1, 36.6, 46.9, 16.4, 88.4, 85.4, NA, 
        19, 33.2, 78.7, 88.2, 111.5, 36.9, 14, 21.9, 28.8, 56.9, 
        84.9, NA, 5.5, 9.4, 70.8, 72.6, 33.8, 55.1, 23.2, 13.1, 
        11.6, 19, NA)), .Names = c("FECHA", "Tesoro"), row.names = c(NA, 
    360L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(FECHA = structure(c(3652, 
    3683, 3712, 3743, 3773, 3804, 3834, 3865, 3896, 3926, 3957, 
    3987, 4018, 4049, 4077, 4108, 4138, 4169, 4199, 4230, 4261, 
    4291, 4322, 4352, 4383, 4414, 4442, 4473, 4503, 4534, 4564, 
    4595, 4626, 4656, 4687, 4717, 5844, 5875, 5903, 5934, 5964, 
    5995, 6025, 6056, 6087, 6117, 6148, 6178, 6209, 6240, 6268, 
    6299, 6329, 6360, 6390, 6421, 6452, 6482, 6513, 6543, 6574, 
    6605, 6634, 6665, 6695, 6726, 6756, 6787, 6818, 6848, 6879, 
    6909, 7670, 7701, 7729, 7760, 7790, 7821, 7851, 7882, 7913, 
    7943, 7974, 8004, 8035, 8066, 8095, 8126, 8156, 8187, 8217, 
    8248, 8279, 8309, 8340, 8370, 8401, 8432, 8460, 8491, 8521, 
    8552, 8582, 8613, 8644, 8674, 8705, 8735, 8766, 8797, 8825, 
    8856, 8886, 8917, 8947, 8978, 9009, 9039, 9070, 9100, 9131, 
    9162, 9190, 9221, 9251, 9282, 9312, 9343, 9374, 9404, 9435, 
    9465, 9496, 9527, 9556, 9587, 9617, 9648, 9678, 9709, 9740, 
    9770, 9801, 9831, 9862, 9893, 9921, 9952, 9982, 10013, 10043, 
    10074, 10105, 10135, 10166, 10196, 10227, 10258, 10286, 10317, 
    10347, 10378, 10408, 10439, 10470, 10500, 10531, 10561, 10592, 
    10623, 10651, 10682, 10712, 10743, 10773, 10804, 10835, 10865, 
    10896, 10926, 10957, 10988, 11017, 11048, 11078, 11109, 11139, 
    11170, 11201, 11231, 11262, 11292, 11323, 11354, 11382, 11413, 
    11443, 11474, 11504, 11535, 11566, 11596, 11627, 11657, 11688, 
    11719, 11747, 11778, 11808, 11839, 11869, 11900, 11931, 11961, 
    11992, 12022, 12053, 12084, 12112, 12143, 12173, 12204, 12234, 
    12265, 12296, 12326, 12357, 12387, 12418, 12449, 12478, 12509, 
    12539, 12570, 12600, 12631, 12662, 12692, 12723, 12753, 12784, 
    12815, 12843, 12874, 12904, 12935, 12965, 12996, 13027, 13057, 
    13088, 13118, 13149, 13180, 13208, 13239, 13269, 13300, 13330, 
    13361, 13392, 13422, 13453, 13483, 13514, 13545, 13573, 13604, 
    13634, 13665, 13695, 13726, 13757, 13787, 13818, 13848, 13879, 
    13910, 13939, 13970, 14000, 14031, 14061, 14092, 14123, 14153, 
    14184, 14214, 14245, 14276, 14304, 14335, 14365, 14396, 14426, 
    14457, 14488, 14518, 14549, 14579, 14610, 14641, 14669, 14700, 
    14730, 14761, 14791, 14822, 14853, 14883, 14914, 14944, 14975, 
    15006, 15034, 15065, 15095, 15126, 15156, 15187, 15218, 15248, 
    15279, 15309, 15340, 15371, 15400, 15431, 15461, 15492, 15522, 
    15553, 15584, 15614, 15645, 15675, 15706, 15737, 15765, 15796, 
    15826, 15857, 15887, 15918, 15949, 15979, 16010, 16040, 16071, 
    16102, 16130, 16161, 16191, 16222, 16252, 16283, 16314, 16344, 
    16375, 16405, 16436, 16467, 16495, 16526, 16556, 16587, 16617, 
    16648, 16679, 16709, 16740, 16770), class = "Date"), Venecia = c(96, 
    142, 58, 77.1, 74.1, 76.3, 21.9, 36.3, 45.5, 91.8, 73.7, 
    58.6, 19.3, 20.3, 62.5, 3.7, 97.1, 100.2, 34.8, 73.7, 46.9, 
    110.5, 156.7, 23.5, 108.3, 200.3, 141.1, 202.5, 70, 63.6, 
    33.9, 13.4, 50.8, 109.5, 118.1, 61.7, 20.1, 68.1, 59.9, 79.6, 
    95.6, 83.3, 10.2, 26.8, 92.5, 191.3, 120.1, 33.1, 37.7, 24, 
    34.7, 75.3, 62.2, 13, 59.2, 28.8, 116.4, 108.9, 103.5, 4.5, 
    24.6, 106.4, 95.9, 59.7, 66.6, 59.3, 96, 10.8, 80.6, 96.9, 
    208.2, 26.9, 65, 36.2, 152.1, 121.9, 71.7, 12.6, 56.4, 28.4, 
    52.3, 65.3, 109.2, 93.3, 39.8, 27.7, 50, 90.1, 30.5, 11, 
    42.7, 20.3, 27.3, 17.9, 153.3, 107.7, 59, 174.3, 65.4, 79.8, 
    79.1, 32.1, 22.8, 14.4, 75.4, 103.5, 201.2, 91, 45.4, 72.2, 
    77.6, 83.6, 89.9, 54.3, 34.8, 26.5, 48.9, 177.9, 81.1, 33.4, 
    7.8, 38, 159.4, 142.3, 90.7, 75, 52.7, 192.3, 72.5, 76.7, 
    87.4, 58, 121.8, 29.1, 121.1, 59.6, 67.9, 70.7, 86.7, 71.2, 
    14.4, 151.2, 91.8, 103, 109.8, 33, 66.3, 77.5, 31.6, 30.9, 
    19.6, 12.4, 38, 68.8, 113.1, 32.6, 13.5, 69.3, 74.3, 76.5, 
    126.1, 25.8, 56, 35, 117.6, 94.1, 81.3, 58.1, 60.8, 67.3, 
    54.7, 68.1, 58.9, 66.2, 21.4, 40.7, 74.2, 149, 150.4, 113, 
    69.2, 24.1, 119.7, 65.3, 44.2, 42.1, 45.2, 47.8, 119.1, 82.4, 
    76.2, 36.7, 53, 35.3, 83.3, 30.1, 88.3, 72.2, 37.4, 31.6, 
    86.5, 73.8, 104.6, 76.9, 11, 27.8, 51.9, 191.3, 47.3, 53.4, 
    67, 4, 34, 29, 41.4, 102.6, 12, 111.2, 132.8, 87.5, 35.4, 
    NA, 5, 73, 43.2, 78.2, 115.1, 103, 25, 76, 61.9, 122, 118, 
    44, 25, 13, 113.4, 157.2, 80, 43.1, 57.6, 40.2, 31.3, 37.8, 
    95.4, 9.2, 51.3, 19.4, 96.4, 101.5, 29.4, 27.6, 38, 26, 190, 
    175, 223, 66, 5, 48, 24, 153, 139, 47, 15, 31, 89, 123, 57, 
    67, 32, 103, 32.8, 156, 89, 113, 80, 51, 141, 112, 142.7, 
    48, 66, 91, 36, 137.5, 303, 69, 48, 44, 107, 86, 48, 93, 
    NA, NA, NA, 186.6, 126.1, 28, 5, 22.5, 6.7, 141.6, 132.9, 
    70.6, 94, 35, 59, 119, 202.6, 121.7, 28, 61, 133, 171.6, 
    176.2, 39, 54, 35.1, 40.7, 162.3, 215, 97.3, 62.9, 52.4, 
    82.8, 152.8, 49.2, 30.1, 53.8, 68.8, 20.8, 131.8, 84.9, 73.1, 
    69.9, 102.1, 84.8, 96.5, 150.7, 29.1, 14.1, 60.4, 24.7, 92.4, 
    171.6, 74, 45.7, 49.4, 73.1, 66.9, 92.4, 48.5, 31.2, 19.5, 
    29.1, 188.4, 124.1, 44.4, 17.2, 31.2, 85.1, 46.3, 24.5, 70.3, 
    30.7, 15.9, 16.6, 20.9, 81.1, 1.5)), .Names = c("FECHA", 
    "Venecia"), row.names = c(NA, 372L), class = "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Can you show us what the variable `novo` contains?

Comment: Please use `dput(novo)`.

Comment: Please format the output properly. Provide a reproducible example ([hint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)).

Comment: Maybe i wasnt clear enough, as far  as i know and search in other questiones, a data frame has to be of a rectangular size, so its not possible to do that, but i wonder, how the example data can be turn in a data frame is its components dont have the same rows?. Anyway i'm working on a solution modifying the csv tables. ;)

Comment: The only solution was to put a common number of rows filled with NA's in case of missing data.